# Combining multiple columns with similar names in Jupyter notebook from an xls import

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm bringing in survey data from an excel sheet where there are multiple columns which have the same title in the excel sheet, when I import them into my dataframe, they're reformatted as value.1, value.2, value.3, etc.

I've been trying to change the dataframe from a wide to a long format, but the variable names don't merge the values, so instead I get each one as a new value name.

In addition, I have to specify all the value names in the conversion, which is tedious, because there's 40+ variants now.

```
import pandas as pd
    
# create a dataframe with an x, x.1, and y, y.2 column
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'x.1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y.1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],})

# add an id column
df['id'] = df.index

# change from wide to long format using melt
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id'], value_vars=['x', 'x.1', 'y', 'y.1'], var_name='variable', value_name='value')
print(df)
```

Where I'm getting this output

```
    id variable  value
0    0        x      1
1    1        x      2
2    2        x      3
3    3        x      4
4    4        x      5
5    0      x.1      1
6    1      x.1      2
7    2      x.1      3
8    3      x.1      4
9    4      x.1      5
10   0        y      1
11   1        y      2
12   2        y      3
13   3        y      4
14   4        y      5
15   0      y.1      1
16   1      y.1      2
17   2      y.1      3
18   3      y.1      4
19   4      y.1      5
```

But what I want is to gather the values like this:

```
    id variable  value
0    0        x      1
1    1        x      2
2    2        x      3
3    3        x      4
4    4        x      5
5    0        x      1
6    1        x      2
7    2        x      3
8    3        x      4
9    4        x      5
10   0        y      1
11   1        y      2
12   2        y      3
13   3        y      4
14   4        y      5
15   0        y      1
16   1        y      2
17   2        y      3
18   3        y      4
19   4        y      5
```

How can I do this? Ideally in a way where I don't have to have a super long list in when I melt the dataframe

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example of your data after input and of the desired output. You can remove the suffix with `df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace(r'\.\d+', '', regex=True)`. To select all the `Value*` columns you could use `cols = list(df.filter(regex='^Value(\.\d+)?$'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned as comment, this is easy if you pre-process the column names with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to remove the `.0` suffix:

```
out = (df
   .set_axis(df.columns.str.replace(r'\.\d+', '', regex=True), axis=1)
   .melt(['id'],
         var_name='variable', value_name='value', # not needed
        )
)
```

*Note that you don't need to specify the `value_vars` if this set is complementary to `id_vars`. `var_name='variable'`/`value_name='value'` are default values, so not needed either.*

Output:

```
    id variable  value
0    0        x      1
1    1        x      2
2    2        x      3
3    3        x      4
4    4        x      5
5    0        x      1
6    1        x      2
7    2        x      3
8    3        x      4
9    4        x      5
10   0        y      1
11   1        y      2
12   2        y      3
13   3        y      4
14   4        y      5
15   0        y      1
16   1        y      2
17   2        y      3
18   3        y      4
19   4        y      5
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JOQNar/1)